# Setting a string from one destination to another

Tags: c#

I want to include the string `"oldSummary"` in the second richtextbox, however all of the summary's functionality belongs to a `streamRead` after opening a file. Is there a way for that when btn1 button is clicked, it will display the `oldSummary` string? At the moment it's blank due to it's global string set to "" but I want it to display the `oldSummary` string set in the `mnuOpen` button.

```
string oldSummary = "";
private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Load up file code which I remove for this example but goes here…

    //Add data from text file to rich text box
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

    //Read lines of text in text file                
    string textLine = "";
    int lineCount = 0;

    System.IO.StreamReader txtReader;
    txtReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Chosen_File);

    do
    {
        textLine = textLine + txtReader.ReadLine() + " ";
        lineCount++;
    }
    //Read line until there is no more characters
    while (txtReader.Peek() != -1);

    //seperate certain characters in order to find words
    char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

    //number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
    int numberOfWords = textLine.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

    int numberOfChar = textLine.Length - lineCount;

    string divider = "------------------------";

    //Unprocessed Summary
    string oldSummary = "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar + divider;

    txtReader.Close();
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string wholeText = "";
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    wholeText = oldSummary + copyText;
    richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
}
```

Comment: A correct indentation of your code could help a lot to understand what's going on here

Comment: I have corrected the indentetion of your code, but some rogue close braces have to be removed, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
string oldSummary = "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar + divider;
```

with:

```
oldSummary = "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar + divider;
```

so that you assign the value to the class field used in `btn1_Click`.

Comment: unbelievable, spent hours trying to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the global variable oldSummary then do not redeclare one with the same name inside the menu open event handler, just use the global one

```
//Unprocessed Summary
oldSummary = "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar + divider;
```